# How to change layout background continuously like marquee using native android

Tags: java, android

I want to implement as showing in below screen.

I found solution with text-view as a marquee. but I want to implement that with Relative or Linear layout background with images.

I am seeing this in IOS App. They were use any third part API of marquee. so any one tell me how to implement with android.

I have used Translation animation , view pager, view flipper. but still I am not getting answer.please help me.

[image]

One important think... All layout will inner of second layout .for example
In above image brown layout is parent of green layout. Like:

```
<relativelayout     android:ID="brownlayout"..>

   <relativelayout android:ID="green layout"./>

<relativelayout/>
```

Sorry for My English. if any mistake.

Comment: Do you wish to slide images horizontally?

Comment: yes, but using with layout background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ViewPropertyAnimator` to help you with that try this to start playing with your layout then you adjust it like you want:

```
layoutToMove.animate().translationX(layoutToMove.getWidth()).setDuration(1500);
```

adjust the `translationX` to set the position of your layout and the `Duration` in milliseconds of the animation.

Comment: thanks @Eury Perez Beltre  for comment . but Still I am not getting solution for this.